# Reason behind the solution to the question

Tags: c, formatting, printf

What is the output of the following and what's the reason behind this?

```
main()
{
    printf("%%%%");
}
```

The answer is "%%", but I don't know why.

Comment: @Paul: I don't see what purpose it would serve, as he knows both the question and answer. "Why" is sort of a lateral thing, answered the same be it homework or not.

Comment: coz only answering a question is not sufficient v need to knw the reason behind it else the knowledge acquired on something would be pretty superficial and Paul it seems u really dont have an answer to my question so s ur feedback

Comment: @GMan: if it's homework then it's better to give hints rather than complete solutions, so that the student has a chance of actually learning something. Too late in this case though.

Comment: @Paul: I know the purpose of the tag, I don't see anything to hint about. Tell him to look up format-specifiers? Might as well paraphrase for him and not waste his time.

Comment: @GMan: particulary in that case a student would have learnt much more by just pointing him to the `man` command. `man printf` (or quivalent on his system) would have given him all he needs.

Comment: @GMan: in this particular case it's a trivial question, but in general we should still aim for the "teach a man to fish" approach, e.g. point him at the man page and/or ask leading questions such as: what is special about `%` in printf format strings ?

Answer (score 8):

`%` is the beginning of a format-specifier. (For example, `"%d"` means "print an `int`".) A `%` after the format-specifier escapes it, printing a single "%".

That is, in the same way `"\\"` results in a single backslash, `"%%"` results in a single percent-sign.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the output could be anything since you didn't print a newline at the end, and also because you didn't include `stdio.h` :-).

However, correcting the two mistakes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%%%%\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The above should print `%%` followed by a newline.

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %.
>
> ...
>
> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> ...
>
> `%`: A `%` character is written. No argument is converted. The complete conversion specification shall be `%%`.

(C99 7.19.6.1).

Comment: The lack of a newline does not make the output undefined.

Comment: @Michael: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/browse_thread/thread/56f1d712aa8ffd31 (or see 7.19.2p2 in C99).

Comment: The C standard allows a lot of idiotic things in file behavior, like random extra 0 bytes appearing at the end of binary files and fixed-size, line-record-based text files. There's a big difference in the standard allowing idiotic things to avoid making ancient legacy systems that can't be fixed non-conformant, and allowing useful diversity to avoid keeping us stuck in the present implementation. On any real present-day system with byte-stream files (one special case is those where binary and text modes are equivalent and documented as such), missing final newline has no ill consequences.

Answer (score 1):

in printf, `%` is usually used to indicate a token such as `%s` or `%d` or `%5.2f`. If you want to output a literal `%`, you use `%%`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Format specifiers are typically introduced by a % character,
and a literal percent sign can be copied into the output 
using the escape sequence %%.
```

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf).

Thus you can print % in the output using %%. The question has a series of % symbols, hence the output is %%.